# Error in jquery lib jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery-1.3.2.min.js in my application. when opening my page i am getting error in IE . Error is in jquery-1.3.2.min.js file at line number 1067

return (text || "").replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, "" );

at this line . Why this error is coming in IE.

Comment: Please show your code. Don't assume it is jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what bit of your script is making a call into jQuery at this point.  As mentioned in the comment you should include your script and any info about the error if you want the problem solved here.